# Gorilla Mux not handling my path

Tags: go, gorilla

When I use the default router from `http` everything works, but if I use the router from `gorilla/mux` instead, I get a 404 page with the body `404 page not found`. As shown in the samples below, everything else is exactly the same.

Why doesn't the `gorilla/mux` router work like this?

#### Working correctly, using `http` routing:

```
package main

import "net/http"

func simplestPossible(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("MWE says OK"))
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", simplestPossible)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
```

#### Not working, using `gorilla/mux` routing:

```
package main

import "net/http"
import "github.com/gorilla/mux"

func simplestPossible(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("MWE says OK"))
}

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/", simplestPossible)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must pass your handler to http package ([ListenAndServe](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServe)):

```golang
http.ListenAndServe(":8000", r)
```

Comment: Sigh. The pluralsight course I'm following doesn't mention anything about that, and the sample files provided don't do it. But now that you show it, it seems so obvious :)